# OMSA on R300 running CentOS7

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac, dell-openmanage

I recently purchased a dell R300 server off Ebay and don't know the setting to log into the iDRAC interface.

I've played around in the boot sequence but there doesn't seem to be a configuration utility there.

I've tried installing OMSA, Dell's utilities that enable management of the server hardware including the iDRAC interface however I'm running CentOS 7 and apparently the package isn't supported in CentOS7 unless its one of Dell's newest servers.

How can I reset the username/password of my iDRAC interface so I can use it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try the LifeCycle Controller (F10 at boot).  It'll be slow as molasses, but it should let you reset the iDRAC settings (assuming the system has an iDRAC to begin with).

That being said, the iDRAC configuration will be the last thing in the BIOS to run before the system begins to boot; you should see its IP settings and get a prompt to hit Ctrl-E.  If you aren't getting that, it might not be there at all.

Comment: When I hit F10 at boot I get the message: 
    "Utility Partition not available.
      Strike the F1 key to continue, F2 to run the setup utility."
Hitting F1 here starts CentOS as usual and hitting F2 takes me to the BIOS setup.  I do get the prompt to hit Ctrl-E for Remote Acess Setup and it lists the IP, etc. of the iDRAC interface, I've also managed to connect to the interface over ethernet so it works, I just don't know the password.  And cant reset it.

Comment: I'm assuming root/calvin doesn't work for the iDRAC password.